# Fastest way to assign only one of multiple function outputs in Python

Tags: python, performance, variable-assignment

Suppose I have a function that returns two values. I am only interested in assigning one of them to a variable. Which is fastest and more Pythonic (or is there a better way)?

```
def fn():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    return a,b

#1
a = fn()[0]

#2
a,_ = fn()

#3
a,b = fn() #and simply ignoring b

#4
x = fn(); a=x[0] #probably not this one but including for completeness
```

I tried `timeit` but it's giving me inconsistent results, with different variations being faster or slower depending on what I assign to `a` and `b` inside of `fn()`. Is there a first-principles way to decide, or a better test for timing?

Comment: I prefer #1, but that is a preference.

Comment: This is mainly opinion based, but I tend to see #2 more and believe it is considered most pythonic

Comment: Using #1 enables earlier garbage collection. This might be an advantage if `b` is large.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko True, although you could do `a, b = fn(); del b`. Tuple unpacking is slightly faster than indexing.

Comment: @PM2Ring Does `a,_ = fn()` perform tuple unpacking?

Comment: @dkv To be accurate I should've called it sequence unpacking, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)